# How cast field with null or text values to DOUBLE PRECISION in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql

I wanna cast my_field to DOUBLE PRECISION in select query. my_field return NULL or Text.

I try this:

```
SELECT
cast(my_table.my_field AS DOUBLE PRECISION) AS my_double_field
FROM mytablename my_table;
```

And this:

```
CASE
  WHEN (my_table.my_field IS NULL)
   THEN NULL
   ELSE my_table.my_field AS DOUBLE PRECISION)
END AS my_double_field
```

I got error:

```
ERROR: invalid input syntax for type double precision: "null"
```

So I try with function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION casttodouble(VARCHAR) RETURNS DOUBLE PRECISION AS $$
DECLARE
  text_colum text := $1;
BEGIN
  RETURN cast(text_colum AS DOUBLE PRECISION);
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

  SELECT
    CASE
      WHEN (my_table.my_field IS NOT NULL)
        THEN casttodouble(my_table.my_field)
        ELSE NULL
      END AS my_double_field,
  FROM mytablename my_table;
```

And got:

```
ERROR: invalid input syntax for type double precision: "null"
Where: SQL statement "SELECT cast(text_colum AS DOUBLE PRECISION)"
PL/pgSQL function casttodouble(character varying) line 5 at RETURN
```

EDIT:

This didn't fail:

```
SELECT
cast(NULL AS DOUBLE PRECISION) AS my_double_field
FROM mytablename my_table;
```

Comment: Just to check: are you sure you don't have a string `'null'` in the column (which is different from the `NULL` value)? IE does `SELECT * FROM mytablename my_table WHERE my_field ILIKE 'null';` return something?

Comment: @Marth Thank you, you are right. I got 'null', not NULL. 
I did not notice that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not to pass `NULL` as `"NULL"` string. `NULL` should be everywhere `NULL` value. You have to distinct between `NULL` and `"NULL"`. If you cannot, then you have to eliminate `"NULL"` string first:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION to_double1(text)
RETURNS double precision AS $$
  SELECT CASE WHEN upper($1) = 'NULL' THEN NULL
         ELSE $1::double precision END
$$ LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE STRICT;
```

But the basic rule is hold `NULL` as real `NULL` not as string `"NULL"`. It is design error.

For single line function is better to use SQL language instead PLpgSQL. There is big chance for inlining instead evaluation of function - what can be faster. Don't forget flags `IMMUTABLE` and `STRICT`. These flags can be used for query optimization.

```
postgres=# \pset null ****
Null display is "****".
postgres=# SELECT to_double1('10101.1');
┌────────────┐
│ to_double1 │
╞════════════╡
│    10101.1 │
└────────────┘
(1 row)

postgres=# SELECT to_double1(NULL); -- correct
┌────────────┐
│ to_double1 │
╞════════════╡
│       **** │
└────────────┘
(1 row)

postgres=# SELECT to_double1('NULL'); -- should not be
┌────────────┐
│ to_double1 │
╞════════════╡
│       **** │
└────────────┘
(1 row)
```

Comment: That's not my database, I only can read from it, so I did not notice 'null' but not NULL in values. Thank, you for advice about functions

Comment: Maybe you can use a function `CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION to_null(text) RETURNS text AS $$ SELECT CASE WHEN upper($1) = 'NULL' THEN NULL ELSE $1 END $$ LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE STRICT`.

Answer (score 2):

Just cast. You don't need all that logic, below I cast string and null to double precision in one `CAST`:

```
t=# with c(v) as (values('2.33'),(null),(3.222))
select cast (v as double precision) from c;
   v   
-------
  2.33

 3.222
(3 rows)
```

Comment: I got error message: ERROR: invalid input syntax for type double precision: "null"

Comment: what's your version of postgres?.. `select version()`

Comment: PostgreSQL 9.6.3

Comment: ```t=# select version();
                                                     version                                                     
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 9.6.3 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 5.4.0 20160609, 64-bit
(1 row)
``` at least confusing...